# How can I derive the KVL equation for the voltage-divider bias circuit of PNP BJT?

Tags: electrical-engineering

When I was studying the "Electronic devices and circuits - Conventional current" book floyd, I came across the following circuit and its KVL equations,

[image: Voltage-divider bias circuit of an PNP BJT]

My doubt is when I apply KVL for the circuit (a), I end up with the $+V_{BE}$ in the equation if I trace the voltage drop in the clock-wise direction. But in the equation, it is $-V_{BE}$.

And for the circuit (b), I could not understand how they got $-V_{EE}-V_{BE}-V_{TH}$ in the equation?

Comment: So, how did you start? And did you consider posting on the electronics / electrical stack?

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question... Please check...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be in electronics - the migrate tool is only giving me the option to select Meta, and nothing else! (On mobile)

Comment: This question would be better suited for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ .